# Rotate a label with image in tkinter

Tags: python, image, tkinter, rotation, label

I am attempting to rotate an label with an image which is on a canvas with tkinter.

I have three images that need rotating (pitch, roll and yaw) and they will eventually rotate according to IMU sensor outputs.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import PhotoImage
from PIL import Image

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Pitch/Roll/Yaw Simulator')

# pick image file
fname = "PRY_Diag_Dials.png"
bg_image = tk.PhotoImage(file=fname)

# get the width and height of the image
w = bg_image.width()
h = bg_image.height()

# size the window so the image will fill it
root.geometry("%dx%d+50+30" % (w, h))
cv = tk.Canvas(root, width=w, height=h)
cv.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')
cv.create_image(0, 0, image=bg_image, anchor='nw')


#add images

pitch = tk.PhotoImage(file="Pitch2.gif")
pitch_lbl = tk.Label(cv, image=pitch,bg="white")
pitch_lbl.image = pitch
pitch_lbl.place(x=60, y=180)

roll = tk.PhotoImage(file="Roll2.gif")
roll_lbl = tk.Label(cv, image=roll,bg="white")
roll_lbl.image = roll
roll_lbl.place(x=325, y=180)

yaw = tk.PhotoImage(file="Yaw2.gif")
yaw_lbl = tk.Label(cv, image=yaw,bg="white")
yaw_lbl.image = yaw
yaw_lbl.place(x=590, y=180)

root.mainloop()
```

How can I rotate the image labels through tkinter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tkinter doesn't have any support for rotating canvas items.

From the [official tcl/tk documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M10) (tkinter is a wrapper around a tcl interpreter):

> Individual items may be moved or scaled using widget commands described below, but they may not be rotated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to simple rotate 90, 180 or flip then you can use `PIL` to `transpose`.

See this link for the details: [Transpose](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.transpose).

Here is the important bits just in case link brakes in the future:

Image.transpose(method)
Transpose image (flip or rotate in 90 degree steps)

Parameters: method – One of:

- PIL.Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT
- PIL.Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM
- PIL.Image.ROTATE_90
- PIL.Image.ROTATE_180
- PIL.Image.ROTATE_270
- PIL.Image.TRANSPOSE

Returns:    Returns a flipped or rotated copy of this image.